# Multivariate Sensitivity Analysis: Find feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Can multivariate sensitivity analysis be used to find the local feature importance of a machine learning model? From the documents, I see that it works for global feature importance, but was not sure if it can be used to explain a particular instance in a dataset.
I was looking into the library SALib.